# Is it possible to send money from India to USA using Paypal?

Tags: money-transfer, paypal

I want to send $500 to a friend based in USA. But after searching on internet I was able to find that we could not send money to USA but on some websites I found we could send the money.

Does anybody know that we can send the money or not?

Comment: Have you looked at the PayPal site to find out?  It's a simple question they'd answer for you, and their customer service is great.  Call them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I have a US based website that accepts payments via PayPal and can confirm we have many customers from India.

[Here is a list of countries PayPal supports.](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/country-worldwide)

Note typically there are some additional fees associated with currency conversion.